# Using OAuth with Twitter in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter, oauth

I am using Twitter as an OAuth provider for ASP.NET MVC 4 web site. I would like to be able to follow up with a registered user at a later date, either by email or via a tweet. Outside of having the user follow me on Twitter, do I have any other options to communicate with the user?

Here is what I unsuccessfully considered:

1. It appears that there is no way to get access to the email address since Twitter OAuth API does not return it.
2. It appears I cannot send a direct message unless a user
   follows me on Twitter.
3. "Read/Write/DirectMessage" permissions seem
   too intrusive -- all I want to do is send a user a message that a
   new product is released -- I don't need any of the write
   capabilities that this level of permissions provides.

To recap, if a user used Twitter to sign in to my website, what are my options to contact that user at a later date?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter's solution for this sort of person-to-person communication is the Direct Message, however, Twitter has (rightfully) decided that both parties need to consent to this channel being available.  This decision is intended to reduce the amount of spam in the Twitter ecosystem.

Posting public tweets that mention the username will get your users' attention, but it is also broadcasting their relationship with your company to the entire Twitter ecosystem.  You will, essentially, be advertising their relationship with your company without their permission.  This approach will bring you headaches sooner or later.

Email is probably a better choice for the sort of announcement to existing customers.